# Signature of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

What is the signature of a pointer that can only point to a fixed memory location in c? I don't know pointers, and I found this question at the back of my textbook to which I cannot find the answer. I know that pointer is a variable whose value is the address of another variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: It helps to speak of "pointer to read-only data" vs "read-only pointer to data". If you say "const pointer" then that's ambiguous.